# The "Guid" type must be a reference type to be used as a "TRelatedEntity" parameter in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the class ArticleEntity

```
public class ArticleEntity
{
    public Guid ArticleID { get; set; }
    public Guid AuthorID {get; set;}
    public BaseWriter Author { get; set; }

    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public string Decricao { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
   
    
    public ArticleStatus Status { get; set; }
   
    public DateTime PublishedOn { get; set; }
    public Admin ApprovedBy { get; set;}
  
    public DateTime RemovedOn { get; set;}
    public Admin DeletedBy { get; set;}
}
```

And BaseWriter, which is an abstract class that's inherited by the Admin class. So far Admin has nothing else implemented

```
public abstract class BaseWriter
{
  
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Matricula { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleEntity> AllArticles { get; set; }
    public WriterProfile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to map it, using the HasOne method to configure two properties to become the primary key

```
 public class ArticleMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ArticleEntity>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ArticleEntity> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Article");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.ArticleID);
        builder.HasOne(u => u.Author);
        builder.HasOne(u => u.AuthorID);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that, in the Configure function I'm getting this error message about the AuthorID

*The type "Guid" must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter TRelatedEntity in the generic type or method "EntityTypeBuilder.HasOne(Expression<Func<ArticleEntity, TRelatedEntity>>)"*,

What's the reason of this message? I'd like to have UserName(string) and UserID(Guid) as primary keys of Article. I'm new in C# and Entity, so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: you dont need to have `builder.HasOne(u => u.AuthorID);`

Comment: But why I don't need it?

Comment: `Author` property here is the referenced entity... so you don't need to have `AuthorID` property explicitly.. it is same as `Admin DeletedBy` and `Admin ApprovedBy` properties.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using is called `Fluent API`, and it is part of `EntityFramework`. This will help you find information easier as you now know what to look for.

---

As for your issue, the HasOne function must point towards a reference Type like a class or anything that can be used as an table. And because baseWriter can be a table it can be used in this context. Whereas ArticleID is struct and doesn't have properties.

Fluent API has a unique way of doing things. You describe the relationships fluently, all within one sentence/function so to say.

Let's look at what your code should look like:

```
builder.HasOne(u => u.Author) // Define the ArticleEntity to BaseWriter relationship
       .WithMany( u => u.AllArticles) // Define the baseWriter to ArticleEntity relationship
       .HasForeignKey (u => u.AuthorID); // Describe what foreign key the baseWriter refers to.
```